# ISerializable vs WCF attributes

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

In C# .NET there is two main possibilities to serialize and object.

1. Implementing the **ISerializable** interface?
2. Using the [DataContract/DataMember] serialization **attribute** of WCF?

What are the differences of this two possibilities and what is the better in term of execution time.

Comment: You mean their performance comparison in WCF services? Because otherwise I don't know how to use WCF serialization engine in non-WCF application, and even if is possible I doubt that it is the recommended way of getting things done.

Comment: So ISerializable is primarily used if you want to do special extensions of serialization, otherwise you can get at least binary serialization more "out of the box". See the nice MSDN page on serialization [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).